# How can I keep Deep Freeze from reverting my TrueCrypt partitions?

Tags: windows, truecrypt

On Windows, I'm trying to use both [Deep Freeze](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Freeze_%28software%29) and TrueCrypt on the same computer. For some reason, DF is reverting my TrueCrypt partitions even when configured not to.

I have two partitions:

- **C:\** for Windows (unencrypted)
- **D:\** for everything else (encrypted with TrueCrypt)

I configured Deep Freeze to revert the C: drive when I reboot, but ignore the encrypted D: drive. Despite this, it's reverting both of them, and I can't figure out why.

**Edit:** D: is an actual partition encrypted with TrueCrypt, not just a file volume.

Comment: Is the D: drive an actual partition, or just a file-volume?

Comment: D: is an actual partition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it up this way (from scratch if you have to / or re-install Deep Freeze)

1. Partition and Format your computer the way you want it.
2. Install TrueCrypt, and mount all your encrypted containers or partitions.
3. While the containers are mounted, install Deep Freeze with the option to only freeze the C drive.

The trick is to install Deep Freeze last, and it can see all the partitions and mounted drives, otherwise, it might default to frozen on any other drives it doesn't see.

That worked for me.

Although I had a problem when I attempted to use Deep Freeze on a TrueCrypt hidden OS, and it got permanently frozen, but that was a couple of years ago. I have not yet tried it again. (Both the decoy OS and the hidden OS were supposed to have been frozen but with thawed data partitions.)

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried thawing your computer, then making the changes you want, rebooting (still thawed), verify that the settings are what you want in DF, and then re-freeze just the C: drive?

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Deep Freeze if it's installed.
If you have TrueCrypt partitions, erase all of them.
Make the partition use TrueCrypt, but not encrypted. That way, you can access it. Then install Deep Freeze, and select C: as the only partition to use (don't encrypt it). Restart the computer, and then encrypt the partition with TrueCrypt. Don't freeze the encrypted partition.